# (JavaScript) Why does a continue statement inside 'if' in a while loop crash the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, while-loop

I want to write a program in JavaScript to print all the numbers from 1 to 20 except 5 and 10. When I use a for loop like this:

```
for (x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
        continue;
    }
    document.write(x + ' ');
}
```

It works properly and prints `1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`.

However, when I try to use a while loop like this:

```
var x = 1;

while (x <= 20) {
    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
        continue;
    }
    document.write(x + ' ');
    x++;
}
```

It makes the webpage unresponsive and I get a prompt asking me to close it. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the following, inside the *for-loop* the *continue* will jump back to the update expression *x++* but in the while loop it will jump back to the running condition *while(x <= 20)*

Referencing the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

> In a while loop, it jumps back to the condition. In a for loop, it
> jumps to the update expression.

Because you are not updating the counter inside your condition

```
while (x <= 20) {
    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
        continue;            
    }
```

x will remain 5 and gets never updated because with the continue inside the while-loop it jumps back to the *running condition*. This will end up in an **endless loop**.

To solve it you can increment the counter before the continue statement inside the *while-loop*

```
while (x <= 20) {
    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
        x++
        continue;
```

```js
// for (x = 1; x <= 20; x++) {
//    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
//        continue;
//    }
//    document.write(x + ' ');
//}


var x = 1;

while (x <= 20) {
    if (x == 5 || x == 10) {
        x++
        continue;
        
    }
    document.write(x + ' ');
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the first case the loop declaration `for (x = 1; x <= 20; x++)` handles incrementing `x` between iterations, so every time the loop body executes, you get a different value of `x`.

In the second case, `x++` is *only* executed if `x` is neither `5` nor `10`. So, when `x` reaches `5` it's the loop will keep executing with `x = 5` forever, since nothing is changing it.